# Lagrange Polynomial

Tags: python-requests, coefficients, decimal-point, rounding-error

How to display coefficient of Lagrange function coefficients without rounding, without 10** or e form. At least monitor 30 decimals.
ex
f.coef
array([ 2.81360229e-12, -4.65044643e-09,  3.40515245e-06, -1.44970799e-03, 3.95473792e-01, -7.16863569e+01,
8.63439193e+03, -6.66353490e+05,2.98987993e+07, -5.94258275e+08])
but I need at least 30 decimals
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If those are `floats`, then you're going to have 16 digits of precision at most. You're interested in the Python `decimal` package. It's part of standard Python, and a quick start can be found in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal).

Comment: Thanks, can you create a script for finding accurate coefficients for the following:
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=[270,280,290,300,310,320,330]
y=[1465,1425,1375,1345,1300,1255,1215]
f=lagrange(x,y)
print(f)
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
x_new=np.arange(250,350,5)
plt.ylim(0,2000)
plt.plot(x_new, f(x_new), 'b',x,y,'ro')
plt.title('lagrange polynomial')
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()

Comment: I have only
array([-2.43055556e-07,  4.39791667e-04, -3.31232639e-01,  1.32913854e+02,
       -2.99694493e+04,  3.60023797e+06, -1.80015545e+08])